# row times column is not a scalar, with custom scalar type

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to use the CppAD scalar type with Eigen.

The following fails to compile:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <cppad/cppad.hpp>
#include <cppad/example/cppad_eigen.hpp>

int main()
{
    using Scalar = CppAD::AD<double>;
    //using Scalar = double;

    Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 1,4> row;
    Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 4,1> col;
    Scalar scalar = 5;
    
    Scalar res2 = row * col + scalar; //fails

    return 0;
}
```

The error is basically that it cannot add a scalar to the result of the multiplication. However, the result of the multiplication is a scalar itself, so it should not be a problem. Indeed, when using `double` as the `Scalar` type, there are no issues.

Here is the compiler error:

```
cppad-eigen-problem.cpp:14:29: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 1, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>, 0>’ and ‘Scalar’ {aka ‘CppAD::AD<double>’})
   14 |     Scalar res2 = row * col + scalar; //fails
      |                   ~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~
      |                       |       |
      |                       |       Scalar {aka CppAD::AD<double>}
      |                       const Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 1, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<CppAD::AD<double>, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>, 0>
```

There is an [issue on the CppAD project](https://github.com/coin-or/CppAD/issues/72), but I am not sure where the problem is:

1. If I use another trivial custom scalar, I cannot reproduce the error...
2. On the other hand, the [CppAD Eigen traits](https://coin-or.github.io/CppAD/doc/cppad_eigen.hpp.htm) for their scalar types looks ok to me.

Versions: Eigen 3.3.7, latest master of CppAD, g++ 9.3.0

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: I agree that the NumTraits seem to fulfill the requirements listed [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html).
While this does not answer your underlying question, note that avoiding the `Product` type solves your problem: `Scalar res2 = row.adjoint().dot(col) + scalar; // works`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, and other workarounds are possible, like using `value()` since I know the result is a scalar: `(row * col).value() + scalar`. However, that is not viable for me, as I have lots of already written code, which works fine with `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is mathematically true that a `(1x1)` matrix is a scalar, C++  is a different story: The return type of `operator*` in `row * col` is not a scalar and neither a `(1x1)` matrix but a product expression. This product expression is implicitly convertible to the scalar type of its operands, in this case `CppAD::AD<double>`.

The reason for the error you see is that `CppAD::AD<double>` is a template and its operators are thus function templates, e.g. something like

```
template<typename T>
CppAD::AD<T> operator+(const CppAD::AD<T>& lhs, const CppAD::AD<T>& rhs);
```

The problem now is that the above *templated* `operator+` cannot be called since there is no implicit conversion in template arguments and exactly this would be needed to cast the product expression to `CppAD::AD<double>`.

That's also the reason why avoiding the product works (e.g. by using Eigen's `.dot` function).

Nevertheless you can solve this problem by e.g. defining an appropriate `operator+`, something like (not tested)

```
template<typename Derived>
CppAD::AD<double>  operator+(const MatrixBase<Derived>& lhs, const CppAD::AD<double> & rhs) {
  return lhs.derived().coeff(0, 0) + rhs;
                     //^^^^^^^^^^^ No need for an implicit conversion
}
```

or you could use [Eigen's plugin mechanism](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html) and add an operator to `MatrixBase`.

Comment: Thanks @dtell! I knew that the result is an expression, but as you said, it can be implicitly converted to a scalar. If I understand correctly, normally the implicit conversion happens because an operator+ taking two scalars is found, and Eigen tries to convert the product expression to one of the operands, i.e. a scalar. When the operator+ is a template, it is not recognized as viable, and so no conversion is triggered and everything fails. Is it correct?
It is just strange to think that recognizing that the product can be converted to a scalar depends on the availability of the operator+

Comment: Basically yes. I'm no language lawyer but as a rule of thumb: You cannot use conversion in the deduction of template parameters.

Comment: Also, your proposed solution has the drawback (I think) that it would allow to sum a scalar to any matrix. Can we add some compile-time check that `lhs` has size equal to (1,1) ?

Comment: Yes, sure. That was just a really quick draft. You should check that.

Comment: @L.Bruce please consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem. Cheers!